# Resume Form Submit after PreventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, sweetalert

I've looked around and found many similar answers but the form submit I have within my code fails. What seems to be missing or incorrect that prevents the form to submit when either 'submit' buttons are clicked and confirmed with SweetAlert?

http://plnkr.co/edit/NL7r4E9UKVjGSBbAwt86?p=preview

```
   <form id='submissionForm' autocomplete='off' method='POST'>
        <button>Save</button>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitTest1' value='Submit 1'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitTest2' value='Submit 2'>
    </form>
```

Clicking "Yes, I am sure" then "Ok" doesn't submit the form.

**UPDATE:**
I've simplified the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/A9aDycYhIkJcTmK5qIUS?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form element has a method named `submit`, but also has the form elements in the form as members.

If you have a `button` in the form named `submit`, you could access it using `document.form1.submit`. However, as that is the same name as the submit method, there is no longer any way of accessing that method. If you use the method to submit the form, that will no longer work.

Use this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhkzBiJ8aT6Msn9IgCvT?p=preview):

HTML:

```
<form id='submissionForm' autocomplete='off' method='POST'>
        <button>Save</button>

        <input type='submit' name='submit1' id='submitTest1' value='Submit 1'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit2' id='submitTest2' value='Submit 2'>
    </form>
```

Comment: vispan has spotted well the issue.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) to remove the event handler before submitting the second time.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/lXUtzlMISxztGVvucFQS?p=preview

As noted in the answer, the fact that you have form elements named "submit" is overriding the `.submit()` method. You should avoid using "submit" as a name in your submit buttons. change that an it should work.

Comment: With this I still get `Uncaught TypeError: form.submit is not a function` in the console when clicking on "OK" of the success message

Comment: Interesting! I've tried out your code and the form still does not submit after SweetAlert's confirmation.

Comment: @theflarenet - As noted in the other answer, the submit name is the problem. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your form object is a plain javascript object and doesn't have access to jQuery's submit method.</s>

Wrap the form object in a jQuery wrapper `$(form).submit()`

Not sure if vanilla javascript is a requirement, as I saw that jQuery was included in the plnkr, but I tested using jQuery's `submit()` method instead of the javascript method, and it worked.

When you create the form variable, make `this` a jQuery object `var form = $(this);`

Comment: submit() is also a standard JS method.

Comment: True, but using jQuery's submit method the form submits. Maybe I should reword this answer